# Como sair de uma função e ir para outra função dentro de uma classe, python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

gostaria de uma ajuda sou novo em programação python, costumava programar em excel(VBA) e tem uma instrução no VBA chamada "Goto" que me ajudava bastante, por exemplo chegava em uma certa parte do codigo que dependendo do resultado ou se desse erro eu escrevia Goto PARTE_1 e ele ia exatamente para a parte do meu codigo onde estava escrito PARTE_1: e não retornava, só seguia em frente. O que eu preciso é saber como fazer isso em python.

Comment: Esse call pelo que entendi é um Goto, o que não tem no Python, o que você pode tentar é a resposta do @de_python. Lembrando que Goto não é considerado uma boa prática

Comment: Boa cara, escrevi errado, é exatamento o Goto, obrigado

Comment: A questão maior é *em que momento você sente falta de um goto* ao trabalhar com Python. É dentro de um loop? `break` e `continue` são formas melhores de controle de fluxo. Dentro de uma função? Use `return` pra sair dela em qualquer ponto. Condicional? Coloque o código ao qual o goto redirecionaria dentro da condição (melhor ainda, em uma função a ser chamada condicionalmente). Evitar erros? Existe `try` e `except` para isso.

Comment: melhor voce colcoar algum exmeplo do código que você quer quer funcione - unçoes pequenas com apenas um if e um print quando precisar, para criar um exemplo mínio e completo.  Senão uma resposta correta vira uma aula completa de programação funcional, e não necessariamente você vai entender, por que não está claro onde você está se perdendo.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar uma função com essa especificação, pode ser até uma função chamada parte_1, exemplo:

```
class MinhaClasse:

    def __init__(self, atributo1, atributo2):
        self.atributo = atributo1
        self.atributo2 = atributo2

    def funcao_primaria(self):
        x = None
        fazendo alguma coisa
        fazendo outra coisa que faz x = True ou x = False

        if x == True:
            self.parte_1()
        else: #se x == False
            self.parte_2()

    def parte_1(self):
        fazendo alguma coisa própria da função
        ...
        return resultado

    def parte_2(self):
        fazendo alguma coisa própria que não é esperado que parte_1 faça
        ...
        return resultado
```

Caso você não tenha uma classe, só retirar a função **init** e todos os self do código como abaixo:

```
def funcao_primaria():

    x = None
    fazendo alguma coisa
    fazendo outra coisa que faz x = True ou x = False

    if x == True:
    parte_1()
    else: #se x == False
    parte_2()

def parte_1():

    fazendo alguma coisa própria da função
    ...
    return resultado

def parte_2():

    fazendo alguma coisa própria que não é esperado que parte_1 faça
    ...
    return resultado
```

Answer (score 0):

Consegui, obrigado a todos, ficou assim o código, exclui a classe, criei um while que roda enquanto o contador for menor que o numero de linhas e dentro dele coloquei if e elif chamando as funções de acordo com a variável "a" e as funções ficaram dentro do try e dentro das funções em si que tem o código eu coloquei os return para sair da função em momentos de erro ou demora para carregar ou etc... e quando ela retorna ela respeita o try que diz exatamente o que fazer modificando a variável "a"

Não sei se expliquei bem ou se o código ficou o ideal mas é o primeiro código em .py que eu faço, deu certo mas com o tempo vou aprimorando. Obrigado novamente, vocês foram fundamentais.

```
a = 5
while CONTADOR_CNPJ <= dfcount:

    if a == 0:
        try:
            consulta(CONTADOR_CNPJ)
            a = 1
        except:
            a = 15
    elif a == 1:
        try:
            CLICA_CLIENTE()
            a = 2
        except:
            a = 15
    elif a == 15:
        try:
            ERRO()
            a = 0        
        except:
            a = 5            
    elif a == 2:
        try:
            GRAVAR = COPIA_DADOS(y)
            a = 3
        except:
            a = 15

    elif a == 3:
        try:
            CONTADOR_CNPJ = FIM(GRAVAR, CONTADOR_CNPJ)
            a = 0
        except:
            a = 15

    elif a == 10:
        try:
            CNPJ = df.loc[CONTADOR_CNPJ, 'CNPJ']
            CNPJ = str('%014d' % int(CNPJ))
            arq.write(CNPJ + "||" 'NAO ENCONTRADO')
            CONTADOR_CNPJ = CONTADOR_CNPJ + 1
            a = 0
        except:
            a = 15

    elif a == 4:
        try:
            iden()
            a = 0
        except:
            a = 5

    elif a == 5:
        try:
            nav = webdriver.Chrome()
            logar(login, senha)
            a = 4
        except:
            a = 15
```